# Names of IBM Q backends

Tags: ibm-q-experience, history

IBM Q backends have many different names, see for example this [link](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/cloud/backends/systems/). We have for example processors called Melbourne, Tokyo, Armonk etc.

I am curious where these names come from? For example, I know that IBM headquarter is placed in Armonk, NY. But what about others? **Is there any special logic behind naming IBM processors?**

Comment: Each time I see their list of devices, I think of [this](https://youtu.be/nIwDAzXEzEM).

Comment: The names are typically locations with an IBM research presence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states that "All quantum systems are given a city name, e.g., ibmq_johannesburg. This name does not indicate where the actual quantum system is hosted."

https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/cloud/backends/configuration

Some cities (e.g., Yorktown) host IBM Research centers.